# Changing georeferenced raster source priority GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, geoserver, arcgis-pro, georeferencing

About 800 historical images have been georeferenced in ArcGIS Pro. A little explanation about the process:

These maps have been clipped in Photoshop and saved as TIFF's. These have been georeferenced in ArcGIS Pro and saved(not exported).

These maps have to be published as WMS on GeoServer. However, most of the maps are being projected to Null Island or somewhere else. So far, I have concluded that GDAL (either in QGIS or GeoServer) won't read the raster sources properly to project the maps in the same way as in ArcGIS.
My best guess is that I need to change the reading priority of the raster sources. For this I've found [GEOREF_SOURCES](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#georeferencing) but I have no clue how to run this configuration on the rasters. How do I use this config?

I have also tried exporting the maps again, which works, but the resolution is decreased so much that the text is not readable anymore. Several export options make no change whatsoever.

Comment: So what do you have now as sources? Mixture of GeoTIFFs and images with tiff+tfw in several projections or what?

Comment: Yes, so geotiffs with .tfw(x), .ovr and .aux files. All in the Dutch coordinate system EPSG:28992